# Neo4j server fails to start with unmanaged extension

Tags: java, neo4j, server, launch

I'm trying to use unmanaged extensions on a neo4j server (version CE 2.3.2), so I'm trying a simple [HelloWorld example](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html) given on the official Neo4j website:

- I've generated the jar file with the "org.neo4j.server.plugins.ServerPlugin" file in the "METADATA/services" folder.
- I put my jar in the "[neo4jInstallPath]/plugins" folder
- I put the following line in the "C:\Users[currentUser]\AppData\Roaming\Neo4j Community Edition\neo4j-server.properties"

  org.neo4j.server.thirdparty_jaxrs_classes=org.neo4j.examples.server.unmanaged=/examples/unmanaged

But when I try to start my Neo4j server, it crashes with the following error:

> Starting Neo4j failed: org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer-ff3335e@3ada3fcf==org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer,-1,false

I've tried several things such as moving the "org.neo4j.server.plugins.ServerPlugin" in some other places, I've tried others Helloworld examples, etc... but I always get the same error when launching the server does somebody knows what to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are combining instructions for deploying a [server plugin](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-plugins.html) with the instructions for deploying an [unmanaged extension](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html). A plugin must inherit from the [ServerPlugin](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/server/plugins/ServerPlugin.html) class. Contrast with an unmanaged extension, which uses JAX-RS to extend the Neo4j server REST API.

The example you linked is an unmanaged extension and therefore your should not include `org.neo4j.server.plugins.ServerPlugin` in your jar. Instead, just ensure your jar includes any dependencies and move to the `plugins` directory and update `neo4j-server.properties` as you indicated above.

Comment: Indeed, I've mixed the 2 concepts, and you were right saying "ensure your jar includes any dependencies": my jar were done "manually" just the wanted class and the MANIFEST.MF file without any dependency, building my jar with maven  adds some dependencies informations. It works fine now, thank you very much.